# How to Connect Database(postgres) to Airflow composer On Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have airflow setup on my local machine.Dags are written in a way that they need to access database(postgres).I am trying to setup similar thing on Google Cloud Platform.But I am not able to connect database to Airflow in a composer.I am Keep getting error "**no host postgres**" Any Suggestions for setting up airflow on GCP or Connecting Database to airflow composer??

Here  Is Link For My Complete Airflow Folder:(This setup works fine on my local machine with docker)

https://github.com/digvijay13873/airflow-docker.git

I am using GCP composer.Postgres Database is in SQL instance. My Table creation Dag is here :
https://github.com/digvijay13873/airflow-docker/blob/main/dags/tablecreation.py

What changes should I do in a My existing Dag to connect it with postgres in SQL instance. I tried Giving public IP address of postgres in Host parameter.

Comment: Your question may be a little broad.  Maybe see if you can't narrow it.  For example, are you using GCP Composer or running Airflow as a custom container?  Where is your Postgres database located?  Is there a specific task/command that is throwing the error?  What have you defined in any Airflow connections?

Comment: I am using GCP composer.Postgres Database is in SQL instance. My Table creation Dag is here : https://github.com/digvijay13873/airflow-docker/blob/main/dags/tablecreation.py    What changes should I do in a My existing Dag to connect it with postgres in SQL instance. I tried Giving public IP address of postgres in Host parameter.

Comment: Are you connecting via SQL proxy as per this [documentation](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/connecting-gcp-composer-to-cloud-sql-via-proxy-305743a388a)? Could you try providing the cluster-IP in the host parameter?

Comment: I tried using IP in host parameter.But Its not working.SQL proxy method will get to work only after rewriting dags code with GCP Cloud Operators.I am looking for solution that work with my existing code.(with minimum modifications)

Comment: For connection through public IP of SQL instance you need to connect as per this Git [thread](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/f011da235f705411239d992bc3c92f1c072f89a9/airflow/providers/google/cloud/example_dags/example_cloud_sql_query.py#L144)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering your main question, connecting a SQL instance from GCP in Cloud Composer environment can be done in two ways:

- Using Public IP
- Using Cloud SQL proxy (recommended): secure access without the need of authorized networks and SSL configuration

**Connecting using Public IP:**
Postgres: connect directly via TCP (non-SSL)

```
os.environ['AIRFLOW_CONN_PUBLIC_POSTGRES_TCP'] = (
    "gcpcloudsql://{user}:{password}@{public_ip}:{public_port}/{database}?"
    "database_type=postgres&"
    "project_id={project_id}&"
    "location={location}&"
    "instance={instance}&"
    "use_proxy=False&"
    "use_ssl=False".format(**postgres_kwargs)
)
```

For more information refer [github](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/f011da235f705411239d992bc3c92f1c072f89a9/airflow/providers/google/cloud/example_dags/example_cloud_sql_query.py#L143)

**For connecting using Cloud SQL proxy:** You can connect using Auth proxy from GKE as per [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-kubernetes-engine) documentation.

After setting up the SQL proxy you can connect Composer to your SQL instance using a proxy.

Exemplar Code:

```
SQL = [
    'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE_TEST (I INTEGER)',
    'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE_TEST (I INTEGER)',
    'INSERT INTO TABLE_TEST VALUES (0)',
    'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE_TEST2 (I INTEGER)',
    'DROP TABLE TABLE_TEST',
    'DROP TABLE TABLE_TEST2',
]

HOME_DIR = expanduser("~")
def get_absolute_path(path):
    if path.startswith("/"):
        return path
    else:
        return os.path.join(HOME_DIR, path)
postgres_kwargs = dict(
    user=quote_plus(GCSQL_POSTGRES_USER),
    password=quote_plus(GCSQL_POSTGRES_PASSWORD),
    public_port=GCSQL_POSTGRES_PUBLIC_PORT,
    public_ip=quote_plus(GCSQL_POSTGRES_PUBLIC_IP),
    project_id=quote_plus(GCP_PROJECT_ID),
    location=quote_plus(GCP_REGION),
    instance=quote_plus(GCSQL_POSTGRES_INSTANCE_NAME_QUERY),
    database=quote_plus(GCSQL_POSTGRES_DATABASE_NAME),
)

os.environ['AIRFLOW_CONN_PROXY_POSTGRES_TCP'] = \
    "gcpcloudsql://{user}:{password}@{public_ip}:{public_port}/{database}?" \
    "database_type=postgres&" \
    "project_id={project_id}&" \
    "location={location}&" \
    "instance={instance}&" \\
    "use_proxy=True&" \
    "sql_proxy_use_tcp=True".format(**postgres_kwargs)
connection_names = [
    "proxy_postgres_tcp",
]

dag = DAG(
    'con_SQL',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='A DAG that connect to the SQL server.',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
)
def print_client(ds, **kwargs):
    client = storage.Client()
    print(client)
print_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='print_the_client',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=print_client,
    dag=dag,
)
for connection_name in connection_names:
    task = CloudSqlQueryOperator(
         gcp_cloudsql_conn_id=connection_name,
         task_id="example_gcp_sql_task_" + connection_name,
         sql=SQL,
         dag=dag
    )
print_task >> task
```